# Getting Developer Metadata using Google Script API on Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

I am trying to get the developer metadata about a spreadsheet using the Google Script API, as found on this website.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.developerMetadata/search

I have tried the following, however I am getting no response back?  Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var fileId = ss.getId();
    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

    var paramsPost = {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
        },
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        payload: JSON.stringify({
            dataFilters: [{
                developerMetadataLookup: {
                    locationType: 'COLUMN'
                }
            }]
        })
    };

    var url = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' + fileId + '?developerMetadata:search';
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, paramsPost);
    var data = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
```

Comment: Is there a metadata associated with a column?

Comment: If you want to retrieve the developer metadata using Sheets API, how about modifying to ``var url = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' + fileId + '/developerMetadata:search';``? Because your endpoint is not correct. ``?`` of ``'?developerMetadata:search'`` is ``/``. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.developerMetadata/search

Comment: This was the issue, if you would like to add it as an answer I can set as correct

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted a modified endpoint as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the method of spreadsheets.developerMetadata.search of Sheets API, please modify the endpoint as follows.

#### From:

```
var url = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' + fileId + '?developerMetadata:search';
```

#### To:

```
var url = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' + fileId + '/developerMetadata:search';
```

- `?` of `'?developerMetadata:search'` is `/`.

#### Reference:

- [spreadsheets.developerMetadata.search](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.developerMetadata/search)

Answer (score 1):

You no longer need to use the REST API directly to access developer metadata.

As of November 14, 2018, methods to access developer metadata were added to the built-in Spreadsheet service. See [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2018#november_14_2018) for details.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I was aware that this could be done via the spreadsheet service, I was just looking for an alternative using the spreadsheet API as well.